# How did I just use an OpenGL 3 feature in a 1.1 context?

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew

I just started programming in OpenGL a few weeks ago, and as people suggested to me, I used GLFW as my window handler. I also used GLEW as my extensions handler. So I go through the whole process of making a vertex buffer with three points to draw a triangle and passing it to OpenGL to draw it and I compile and run. No triangle draws, presumably because I didn't have any shaders. So I think to myself "Why don't I lower my OpenGL version through the context creation using GLFW?" and I did that. From OpenGL 3.3 to 1.1 and surely enough, there's a triangle. Success, I thought. Then I remember an article saying that vertex buffers have only been introduce in OpenGL 3, so how have I possibly used an OpenGL 3 feature in a 1.1 context?

Comment: Without the code, I am guessing that you have set OpenGL version with `glfwWindowHint`.  Have you checked the actual version afterwards with `glfwGetWindowAttrib`?

Comment: Correct, I have used glfwWindowHint to set context version major and minor, and no I have not checked.

Answer (score 3):

The graphics driver is free to give you a context which is a different version than what you requested, as long as they are compatible. For example, you may get a v3.0 context even if you ask for a v1.1 context, as OpenGL 3.0 does not change or remove any features from OpenGL 1.1.

Additionally, often times the only difference between OpenGL versions is what extensions that the GPU must support. If you have a v1.1 context but `ARB_vertex_buffer_object` is supported, then you will still be able to use VBOs (though you may need to append the `ARB` suffix to the function names).

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. When you said that I had to append ARB as a suffix to the function names, why do I have to do this? And what will happen if I don't?

Comment: Extension functions have suffixes (usually `ARB` or `EXT`) to distinguish them from core functions. There's usually no difference between the extension function and its corresponding core function, though not all extensions have been added to the core.